# Sugar sync Integration IOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone

I want to integrate the sugar sync in my ios project . Please suggest me the example source code or guidelines . Is the sugar sync developer is paid to get the client id and client secret ?

Comment: I have looked at https://www.sugarsync.com/dev/getting-started.html ., here there is java code . I need objective c

Comment: If you had googled properly, you would have got their SDK from this link: https://github.com/huadee/sugarsync-ios ... Took about 2 mins..

Comment: i tried this one already., but it's getting apple linker error .

Comment: target specifies product type 'com.apple.product-type.framework.static', but there's no such product type for the 'iphonesimulator' platform

Comment: Could this help? https://github.com/kstenerud/iOS-Universal-Framework/issues/91